# I can't get value of email input

Tags: jquery, html

My code does not seems to work. I give it some tests and it looks like email value is empty even if the for is filled. `var email = $("#email").val();` does not return any value

I tried to `alert` the value of `email` and it is empty, that's why code does not work. I get an email if i remove `boolMAIL == true`, so I am sure this is the problem but I don't know why it is empty.

```js
// KLIK NA GUMB RAZREDA gumb KLIČE action_page.php

// PHP SPOROČI JQUERY ALI JE BIL MAIL POSLAN ALI NE
// ČE JE BIL POSLAN NAPISŠE TO PA TO DRGAČ PA NEKI DRUZGA
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("button#potrdi2").click(function() {
    // event.preventDefault(); 
    // var formData = $('#my_form').serialize();
    var pogoji = $("#pogojiinput").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var boolPogoji = $("#pogojiinput").is(':checked');
    var boolMAIL = email.includes("@");
    var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&pogoji=' + pogoji;

    if (boolMAIL == true && boolPogoji == true) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "action_page.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString, // tole je potrebno se popravit za MAIL iz obrazca
        success: function(result) {
          $(".response").show();
          $(".response2").hide();

          $("#obrazec").hide();
          $(".prijavatext").hide();

          alert("poslano");
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(".response2").show();
      alert("not send");
    }
  });
});

var loc = window.location.href + '';
if (loc.indexOf('http://') == 0) {
  window.location.href = loc.replace('http://', 'https://');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email *" required/>
  <button class="submit" id="potrdi2" type="button" onclick>POŠLJI</button>
  <div class="checkboxes" id="pogoji" style="width:100%;">
    <label>
              <input id="pogojiinput" type="checkbox" checked required>
              <span style="color:white; font-size:14px;line-height:18px;font-weight:700;">Sprejemam splošne pogoje poslovanja in se strinjam z obdelavo osebnih podatkov GDPR.</span>
            </label>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Now that I made your code runnable (and removed the syntax error in your alert()) then I can't see any problem...if you include the @ in the field, then it will run the AJAX request (of course in this demo it doesn't actually work to run the call, but it definitely enters the block where it gets sent. Perhaps a different problem is occurring, on the server-side, which is preventing the email from sending.

Comment: The only other thing I can think is maybe you ought to uri-encode your dataString before sending. Or if you just pass `data: { "email": email, "pogoji": pogoji }` in your AJAX options, then jQuery will correctly encode and format it for you, and you don't need `dataString` at all. It's usually better not to create your querystring manually, if you can avoid it, since you might forget (as in this case) to take care of encoding issues.

Comment: Yeah, if you change nothing about your code at all and just run `alert(email)` immediately after assigning it you'll see that it's getting the value from the email input. Your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: But  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    
                   alert(email);                   is empty

Comment: Sorry, i found that the problem - i had two forms and it took an emty value from another form. Thank you all for help.